# How long is a higgs boson stable for before it fully decays?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs

How long after the creation of a higgs boson is it stable for on average?

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer, the  [Higg's Boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson)  is predicted to have a mean lifetime of 1.56 x 10<sup>-22</sup> s.

Comment: this link is relevant, as the measured width of the Higgs is connected to the lifetime http://www.science20.com/quantum_diaries_survivor/precise_bound_higgs_boson_width-132349 . experimentally they have only set bounds. (the lifetime is inversely proportional to the intrinsic width)